# Creating a random number generator in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a webpage the looks like a health monitor and I need to create a random number generator that will act as the heart monitor. Here is what I have:

```
<?php

function functionName()
{
    return rand(5, 15);
}

?>

<html>
<body>

<?php 

    $i = 0;

while ($i <= 10) 
{
    echo functionName();
    echo "</br>";
    $i++;
}

?>


</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that number are printed one after another and I need them to just show up in the same place but be different. In other words if I have a section that says "Heart Best Per Seconds: ", I will need a new number to show up there every few seconds in place of the other.

Does anyone know how to do this? I've seen things similar to this so I'm pretty sure that it's doable.

Comment: You tagged this with javascript, so try it. Take a look at setInterval.

Comment: Since you tagged it `jquery`, you can mix [`jQuery.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) and [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout) client side, adding simple `<?php echo functionName(); ?>` server side as response.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to do it in PHP. Just make a timer in JS that spits out a random number and sets it to an html tag.

Comment: Yau can try Node.JS to run JavaScript code on the server as a cron job. Cron is a time-based job scheduler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 5 + 1)) + 5;
  document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = i;
}, 1000);
```

```html
 <span id="random"></span>
```

this maybe? using [Math.random();](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) and [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: @FortunaIwasaki, you should use this if you want to be free of PHP.

Comment: @Amin Gharavi Why not
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1; ?

Comment: @RobertoSepúlvedaBravo 'Math.random()' gives you a number between 0 and 1 with the exclusion of 1 so your number is always less than one. lets say your number is 0 then the result of your var is (0*15)+1 which is 1.

Comment: @AminGharavi but I've tested your code with Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) + 1; and works fine, it returns random numbers and not just the number 1.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish what you want, you might have to use a combination of JavaScript's JQuery and PHP. For starters, create a file, `randomnumber.php`

```
<?php
die(rand(5,15));
?>
```

and, on your `index.php`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- load JQuery from Google CDN -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 id="randomNumber"></h2>
    </body>
    <script>
    function getRandom() {
        setInterval(function() {
            $("#randomNumber").load("randomNumber.php");
        }, 3000) // delay in milliseconds
    }
    getRandom();
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate random numbers using `Math.random()`.

Round a number downward to its nearest integer using `Math.floor()`.

And use `setInterval()` to run the function at particular interval.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 5 + 1)) + 5;
  document.getElementById("hbeat").innerHTML = 'Heart Beat Per Seconds : ' + i;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span id="hbeat"></span>
```

Comment: If you look at the php its using `rand(5, 15)`. [rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) returns a random int between 5 and 15 thats why i used `Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 5 + 1)) + 5;`